# How do I detect collisions in a parametric equation$?$ (Lissajous curve)$?$

Tags: parametric, collision-detection

Let's say you have a simple parametric equation where $x= \sin(3t)$ and $y=\cos(7t).$ This is a pretty simple parametric equation that generates a relatively complicated Lissajous figure.

You can check it out here pretty easily: www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric+plot

(If I presented the entire web address for the equations, then it would be kind of a mess in this posting)

But, what I'm trying to do is find the intersection points.  I count $32$ of them.  But what if I want to do it without having to tediously count each one visually off the graph$?$  How would I do that$?$  What's the general approach$?$  The reason I'm asking is because I want to make some figures out of wood on a CNC machine, and I need to know the locations of the intersections so I can correctly raise or lower the cutting tool.

What's the general approach$?$  I just used this Lissajous figure as an example, but what would I do if I had an parametric equation like 
$$x = \sin(3t)-\cos(3t^2)$$ 
$$y = \tan(t^4) + \sin(6t)$$ 
and I have no idea how the curve looks$?$

TYIA

Comment: *What's the general approach ?* - This is a [very](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rLSH-81yT7s&t=67) good question...

Comment: Lucian, if you were smart enough, you'd answer the question, not be a wise-guy.  How did you get 35,000 rep points with such a poor attitude?

Comment: And, the general approach is to just solve for t for the x(t) and do likewise for y(t) and then solve.  What you get is something that has multiple meanings depending on what you choose for n, which gets introduced because arcsin(x) has multiple solutions, each offset by 2 Pi n.